# Double quotes are not being escaped in a loop

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I have a csv file (i.e. `test.csv`) and I have to find the double quoted strings only in that file. These double quoted strings need to be found in one particular column (i.e. 7th Column). 
Following are the file contents:

> ```
> Company,Project Code,Level 1,New Level 2,New Level 3,Task Number,Level 4 Description,Year,Period,Currency,Cost
> WHITE ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY,123456,A,A- AB,A-AB-ABC,A-AB-ABC-XYZ,"Hello , World",2020,February,AAA,9900000
> WHITE ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY,123456,A,A- AB,A-AB-ABC,A-AB-ABC-XYZ,"My , World",2020,February,AAA,9900001
> WHITE ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY,123456,A,A- AB,A-AB-ABC,A-AB-ABC-XYZ,"Your , World",2020,February,AAA,9900002
> ```

I have written a loop to go to each line then find that if there is any double quote there. I am able to loop through each line but the double quotes are not being found. I have tried with `find` and `findstr` command as well. I have tried with `\`, `^` and `"` as escape characters for the double quotes, but nothing is working.
Below is my code (with double quote as escape character):

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN (test.csv) DO (
    set line=%%a
    echo !line!
    find """" !line! && (
                echo "Double quotes found"
                ) || (
                echo "Double quotes not found"
                )
    pause
)
```

Please help!

Comment: looks like you rather need `echo !line! | find """" && ..`

Comment: I have to wonder  why there is a need to find out if field 7 uses enclosing QUOTATION MARK characters. Because of the wide variety of CSV implementation, processing with cmd.exe is difficult. What is the real goal of this effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) expects the second parameter to be a file path but not a literal string, so you cannot do `find """" !line!` to find a literal `"` in the string represented by `!line!`. To search a string you will have to use a [pipe (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
echo(!line!| find """" && (echo Found quotes.) || (echo No quotes found.)
```

The escaping of a literal `"` by `""` is correct though, but this is specifically for the `find` command.

---

Anyway, there may be no need to use `find` with a pipe, which is quite slow and might be troublesome when it comes to special characters. Since fields containing commas or quotes should be quoted as per the [CSV format specification][fmtcsv], you could just take care of the surrounding quotes, like in the following example.

If no field is blank (so no adjacent `,` appear) and there is no (quoted) field before the 7th one that contains `,`, set the `tokens` and `delims` options of the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to get the seventh field. Then you can make use of the [`~`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the `for` meta-variable to remove surrounding or leading `"` and compare the result with the plain meta-variable:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=7 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("test.csv") do (
    if not "%%~a"=="%%a" echo The 7th field is quoted: %%a
)
```

(How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file.)
[fmtcsv]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180
(Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files)